# Using Boto to tell when a file has successfully been uploaded to Glacier

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-glacier

Currently I am using Amazon Web Services(AWS) and to open an S3 bucket, save its contents to a directory in an EC2, I then create a tar file from everything that is in that directory and push that tar file to AWS Glacier. The last step that I was trying to accomplish was to have the script terminate when the tar file has been successfully upload to AWS Glacier (Which takes 3-5 hours).

Currently I am stumped as to how to take the archive_id and ask the vault if the tar file has been successfully loaded.

To interact with AWS Glacier I have been using the python boto tool. I included the python\boto code that uploads the file to glacier and some of the quick tests I have tried to run to just figure out if the code has successfully been uploaded or not. So far all of the tests return false.

I excluded a few tests about the status_code which was also returning false for everything as well and when I try to print out any of these only the not completed and in progress (As expect) prints out anything, yet when I try to match the archive_id or retrieve_job to what is returned in the list of jobs I get no matches. An additional note is the lists that these are saved in when it is printed they all the same (  Job(arn:aws:glacier:us-east-1:232412618534:vaults/glacier-poc) )

How to return true when the job is completed?

```
    import boto
    import sys

    ACCESS_KEY_ID = "..."
    SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "..."
    FILENAME = sys.argv[1]
    GLACIER_VAULT_NAME = sys.argv[2]

    connection = boto.connect_glacier(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    vault = connection.get_vault(GLACIER_VAULT_NAME)

    archive_id = vault.upload_archive(FILENAME)

    open("glacier.txt", "a").write(FILENAME + " " + archive_id + "\n")

    retrieve_job = vault.retrieve_archive(archive_id)

    a = vault.list_jobs(completed=True)
    b = vault.list_jobs(completed=False)

    print "Is In Completed List"
    print archive_id in a
    print "Is In NOT Completed List"
    print archive_id in b

    print "Is In Completed List"
    print retrieve_job in a
    print "Is In NOT Completed List"
    print retrieve_job in b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [Boto and Glacier guide](http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/10/24/getting-started-with-boto-and-glacier/), you can either poll it manually from boto or you can set up Amazon Simple Notification Service to notify you when the job is done.

```
archive_id = vault.upload_archive("mybackup.tgz")
retrieve_job = vault.retrieve_archive(archive_id)

# if the job is in progress
job_id = retrieve_job.id
retrieve_job = vault.get_job(job_id)

if retrieve_job.completed:
    job.download_to_file("mybackup.tgz")
```

You can use boto's **set_vault_notifications** function set the SNS notifications.

```
notification_config = {'SNSTopic': 'my_notification_topic',
                       'Events': ['ArchiveRetrievalCompleted',
                                  'InventoryRetrievalCompleted']}
vault.set_vault_notifications(vault, notification_config)
```

[Here](https://github.com/dmiyakawa/glacier_exp_py/blob/master/wait_for_job_complete.py) is an extensive example of waiting for an upload by setting up SNS notification subscriptions to SQS queue service.

Comment: So I am not sure why but I am having problems with this. When I have been trying to check to see if its complete I put it into a while loop to keep checking until it got that the retrieve_job.completed returned true. So far I have tried 3 or 4 different ways and have not had any success. Any helpful tips? I am not trying to download it, just check to see if it is still there